# How to link to a Markdown section in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, markdown, mylyn-wikitext

If you have the following fragment in `README.md`

```
## Developers guide
...
Check the [set up guide](#Developersguide)
```

you will get a warning `Cannot resolve element with id 'Developersguide'`.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Markdown Mylyn Wikitext, the automatic anchor generation, replaces all spaces with hyphens and makes everything lowercase.

```
Check the [set up guide](#developers-guide)
```

will work just fine.